# Echo two separate javascript getElementById's from php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have PHP code that looks something like this which works fine on its own.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('flightTime3').innerHTML = </script>Dep: ";
```

However if I want to set the innerHTML of another element like so:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('flightDate3').innerHTML = </script>Arr: ";
```

The browser interperates it as setting the innerHTML of the first element only. So, the element with id flightTime3 shows "Dep:      Arr:     " and the element with id flightDate3 shows nothing.

How can I break up the javascript within the PHP so that it is recognised as two separate commands?

Comment: This code makes no sense. either of the javascript blocks are incomplete because the `.innerHTML = ` statements are never completed.

Comment: @admcfajn - The fact is, it does work, I don't care how.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing `<script>` tags before assigning a strings to `.innerHtml` by Javascript. Place assignment before you close the `<script>` tag.

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.getElementById('flightTime3').innerHTML = 'Dep:';</script>";
```

Comment: It does not work! If you had read the question properly you will see that I said that it works fine on its own. When I move the script tag to the end, it does not echo anything.

Comment: Hey! I don't know the complete code, but in these two examples that u pasted here You have obvious logical errors. Complete javascript code must be inside "script" tags. If u want to assign innerHTML of some DOM element, then You must do assignment inside the script with a proper syntax. If You do this outside the script it;s no longer interpreted as javascript code.

These are javascript basics. Here u have innerHTML syntax:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: There was mising ending quote mark in my code. Try it now.

Comment: I understand that there are logical errors, however, the code I posted does work. Would be grateful if you could explain how.

Comment: I can't explain without knowing complete code. I can only speculate that U echo it with PHP inside the element 'flightTime3'.